# How to tell if sequence number has been incremented from transaction post response

Tags: horizon

Is there a straightforward way to ascertain from the horizon txn post response if the seqno has been incremented?

For example, an `underfunded` operation will cause the seq number to increment, but a `bad_auth` won't. Both responses are similar. They have no results meta field, and a result code of `tx_failed`.

This [other question](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/274/when-is-account-sequence-number-incremented) talks about why it happens and in which circumstances, but I am interested in how to determine whether it happened, without having to enumerate those different circumstances.

<s>Looking at [github.com/stellar/go/issues/430#issuecomment-385813801](https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/430#issuecomment-385813801) it seems the answer might be to check for the presence of `/extras/result_codes/operations`.</s> (edit: no). A more explicit field would be good.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is account sequence number incremented?](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/274/when-is-account-sequence-number-incremented)

Comment: Yes, I saw that other question, but I think it's different. That talks about why it happens and in which circumstances. This question asks about how to determine whether it happened, without having to enumerate those different circumstances. Looking at https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/430#issuecomment-385813801 it seems the answer _might_ be to check for the presence of `/extras/result_codes/operations`. A more explicit field would be good.

Comment: agree with Bartek. At the response, you need to check `"result_xdr"`. That is some base64 string like `"AAAAAAAAAGT////2AAAAAA=="`, and the behaviour is deterministic such that some result_xdr always increases sequence number while some others always not.

Comment: p.s. Do NOT rely merely on the transaction response message, but go for the `result_xdr`. For example, with the same message "txBadSeq", there are **TWO DIFFERENT CASES** - see here https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/946/for-txbadseq-when-is-tx-fee-charged

Comment: Thanks @cesarm - I've implemented `sequenceIncremented` in terms of `feeCharged`. https://github.com/Synesso/scala-stellar-sdk/blob/master/src/main/scala/stellar/sdk/model/response/TransactionPostResponse.scala#L20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently not possible without enumerating through the list of reasons, and agreed that it might be valuable to file an issue that exposes this information from a Horizon response.